# Why my Android App crushed because of openstream()?

Tags: android, url

I just want to use google weather api

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        InputStream is = new URL("http://www.baidu.com").openStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

I don't knwo why these code cause crushes.It should be right in Java?Please Help me

My device is Google Nexus S,and I also tried working on AVD it crushed too

Comment: Could you please attach a stacktrace or the error output from Logcat?

Comment: it is not giving any exception.

Comment: Does your app include INTERNET as a uses-permission in its manifest?

Answer (score 1):

It probably crashes because you doing network stuff on the UI Thread.

Put the work in an AsyncTask or a Thread and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too. But now, [i have been solved this problem by reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
about the thread use.

You need to create a worker thread to work for open the URL stream rather than using the main thread(UI thread).